# Easy-to-use GUI that is zoomable and pannable?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface, opengl

I am looking for a GUI toolkit that is easy to use and cross-platform. Another major requirement of the GUI is that it should support zoom and pan. For example, I should be able to zoom in on a picture and enlarge buttons.

Something like this:

http://eaglemode.sourceforge.net/video.html

But it should have Windows support also (which to the best of my knowledge Eagle Mode doesn't have).

From what I understand, QT is a good UI and it can draw right on top of the OGL window. I think it resets the matrix before drawing the buttons. If I can prevent that reset, the GUI can be zoomed along with the rest of the items. Is there a simple hack to do just that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

This is doable in Qt 4.4 and above using the [Qt Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html).  It makes it very easy to make these types of interfaces, since Widgets can now be placed on the scene (QGraphicsScene) using QGraphicsWidget and QGraphicsLayout.

The framework supports zooming, panning, rotating, etc - with animation.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you give me a link to a very simple example (kind of like hello world). I am new to all this!

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you install Qt, the demo in demos\embeddeddialogs is a good example.  It shows many windows, embedded, with zoom (plus rotation) on mouse over.

Comment: @madiyaan Don't start developing with Qt4.4, Qt4.5.1 is already released. Have a look at the Qt4.5 SDK

Comment: @TimW: I agree, I'd use the latest stable release - but any version later than 4.4 will support this, and work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Piccolo2D](http://www.piccolo2d.org/), which has Java and .NET bindings.

It is the successor of [Pad++](http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/pad++/), which was well ahead of its time: